# Angular 8: (Angular material tabs)How to toggle between multiple tabs with prev and next arrows?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

I want to toggle between multiple tabs on clicking with previous and next arrows in **Angular Material Tabs** as well as i want to show 3 tabs on 1st show than when a user will click on next arrow the next 3 tabs will get shown using angular material.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="0">
  <mat-tab>
</mat-tab
</mat-tab-group>
```

change selected index on the arrows programmatically with functions and your requirements will be fulfilled.
If you are new and cannot do it just tell me and I will share some demo example